# How can I back up 2 internal drives to a single Time capsule?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I recently reinstalled Lion on an SSD and have all my media on the original HDD on my MBP.  I was hoping Time Machine would recognize my existing backups in Time Capsule but it wants to start a new backup image. Also, it looks like Time Machine wants to only back up my SSD. So, my questions are:

1. Can I back up both drives to one time capsule image as if they were a single logical drive?
2. How can I access my old backed up data in the existing image?

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine's thinking is backup everything except what you tell it not to and the time machine hard drive itself. It should not matter how many drives you have connected, they should all be backed up to the time capsule just fine. In other words, you can backup multiple sources but only on one destination, as long as this destination shows up as a single logical drive in the Finder.

Just check in Sys Prefs > Time Machine > Options if the other HD isn't just simply added to the list of exceptions, don't see how it would end up there by itself, but just in case.

And I don't think you can keep working with the same backup, since you divided the data in to 2 separate logical drives. Time Machine just does not think like that. Better start from scratch, perhaps backing up the current backup set to another drive if you need to preserve all the previous backups... Some people need to be able to go back in time to a specific point. I care only to have one up-to-date copy, don't care much about having 30 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can back up the drives, but not as one logical drive. The backup will be of your computer then, inside the computer's backup will be the two drives.
2. I have never mounted a Time Machine image, but on a Leopard Time Machine backup (which doesn't have an image), you can see and access each of the drives separately. So, my guess is that you more than likely can.